# How to read/write the pixels of the screen

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible in any way to read/write pixels of a screen in VB.NET?

Comment: pixels of the whole screen in your monitor or just the program you have coded?

Comment: @Malky.Kid The whole screen

Comment: `System.Drawing.Graphics.CopyFromScreen`  writing is illadvised since that is Windows job